# cvWriteFrame throws IplImage * : could not convert to CvMat error in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to build a video from jpeg images in python.

This is the code I have.

```
    codec = highgui.CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1')
    fps = 25
    colored = 1
    size = (float(width), float(height))
    video_writer = highgui.cvCreateVideoWriter(
                'out.mpg', codec, fps, cv.cvSize(1440, 553), True)


    pictures = os.listdir(folder)
    for picture in pictures:
        picture = '%s/%s' % (folder, picture)
        highgui.cvWriteFrame(self.video_writer, picture)
```

with height, width, and folder already defined somewhere else.
When I run the code, I get the following error:

```
Output #0, mpeg, to 'out.mpg':
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 1440x553, q=2-31, 50964 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
[mpeg @ 0x29425c0] VBV buffer size not set, muxing may fail
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ips.py", line 109, in <module>
    main()
  File "./ips.py", line 62, in main
    video.build(configs['maps']['folder'])
  File "/home/martin/Formspring/maraca-locator-94947aa/encoder.py", line 34, in build
    highgui.cvWriteFrame(self.video_writer, picture)
TypeError: %%typemap(in) IplImage * : could not convert to CvMat
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any idea what is causing this ? Is there a preferred way to build a frame ?

Answer (score 1):

`cvWriteFrame()` needs a valid `IplImage*`, and you doesn't seem to have one.

Consider the following code:

```
pictures = os.listdir(folder)
    for picture in pictures:
        picture = '%s/%s' % (folder, picture)
        highgui.cvWriteFrame(self.video_writer, picture)
```

`listdir()` returns a list containing the names of the entries in the directory given by `folder`. After that, you declare `picture` to iterate on this list, so it stores only one entry. This is where you are getting confused: at this point, **`picture` is just a string**.

Before calling `cvWriteFrame()` you need to load the image data from the disk and check if it was loaded successfully:

```
pictures = os.listdir(folder)
    for picture in pictures:
        picture = '%s/%s' % (folder, picture)
        img = cv.LoadImage(picture)
        if not img:
            print "!!! Could not load image " + picture 
            break

        highgui.cvWriteFrame(self.video_writer, img)
```